# How to disable goBack and goForward on WKWebview

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiwebview, wkwebview

Firstly, I am using `WKWEbView` framework of Apple support on iOS8. I am using it to load content from the web. But I don't know how to disable `goBack` and `goForward` like `UIWebView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures` property on WKWebView.

Comment: I am trying but it run very well on iOS9. But on iOS8, it crashed and this is a log:  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_CSIRenditionBlockData gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7bfc75e0'

Comment: The default should be NO anyway so do you need to do anything at all? Can you stop it in the debugger and `po  0x7bfc75e0` or whatever the address happens to be when you run it. It might give you a clue as to what is happening.